# Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?

Tags: reference-request, programming

I consider myself a pretty good *Mathematica* programmer, but I'm always looking out for ways to either improve my way of doing things in *Mathematica*, or to see if there's something nifty that I haven't encountered yet. Where (books, websites, etc.) do I look for examples of good (best?) practices of *Mathematica* programming?

Answer (score 526, accepted):

Here's a collection of resources that I started on Mathgroup ([a collection of Mathematica learning resources](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/0014d2ca042a76c2#)) and updated [here at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673695/884752). As this site is dedicated to *Mathematica* it makes more sense to maintain it here. This represents a huge amount of information; of course it's not exhaustive so feel free to **improve** it! Also, don't hesitate to **share** it and **suggest** other interesting links! Remember, you can always search the online [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) of *Mathematica*, that is identical to the built-in help of the latest software version.

Links to more advanced aspects of the program that you can start to appreciate once you understand the basics are provided in separate answers (below) as this post became too large.

- [Tips and Tricks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8617/66)
- [Advanced evaluation, patterns and neat algorithms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28073/66)

### Introduction

- If you're just beginning try to have a look at these videos.
  [Mathematica Basics](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=86&page=2&video=489), [Elementary Programming in Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/search.php?Search=Jon%20McLoone&x=0&y=0&sortBy=date&video=409)
  [Hands-on Start to Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/handsonstart/)
  [Several introductory videos by Jon McLoone](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/search.php?Search=Jon%20McLoone&x=0&y=0&sortBy=date)
  and many other [video introductions and tutorials from the official Wolfram website](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/channels.html)
- [An elementary introduction to the Wolfram language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction)
  [Fast introduction for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers)
- [Is it necessary to have a prior computational background or is it possible to learn Mathematica as a first programming language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8515/66)
- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/66)
- [How To-s](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/HowToTopics.html): full solutions for particular tasks from the online documentation
- [Easy-to-understand animations](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/) explaining common *Mathematica* functions
- [Sal Mangano's videos](http://vimeo.com/user4552113/videos) for using pure functions, `Part` and patterns
- [Introductory videos of various applications of *Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2011/presentations/)
- [What is the best Mathematica tutorial for young people?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/733/66)

### Basic advices for people new to *Mathematica*

**Functional style**

Avoid iterative programming using loops like `For` or `Do`, use instead functional programming functions [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scan.html), [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html), [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html), [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html), ... and pure functions. This makes the code cleaner and faster.

- [Functional Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html), [Functional Programming: Quick Start](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/dev001.html)
- [Pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)
  [What does # mean in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19035/66)
- [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/66)
- An example: [Programming a numerical method in the functional style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22413/66)
- [How to understand the usage of Inner and Outer figuratively?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57760/66)

**Transpose and dimensions**

- Something not easy to guess alone at the beginning: if you have `x={1,2}` and `y={3,4}`,
  doing `Transpose[{x,y}]` or `{x,y}`<kbd>ESC</kbd> tr <kbd>ESC</kbd> in the front end will produce `{{1,3},{2,4}}` (format compatible with `ListPlot`). This [animation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Transpose.html) helps understand why.
- You can also use the second argument of [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) to reorder the indices of a multidimensional list.
- Don't forget to regularly control the output of the lists you generate using [`Dimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dimensions.html).

**Get familiar with shorthand syntax (`@`, `&`, `##`, `/@`, `/.`, etc.)**

- [Operator Input Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)
- [when is f@g not the same as f[g]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/66)

**Programming easily**

- **Getting help**: Execute `?Map` for example for a short description of a function, or press <kbd>F1</kbd> on a function name for more details and examples about it. You can solve many problems by adapting examples to your needs.
- **Auto-completion**: Start typing the name of a function and (in Mathematica 9+) select from the pop-up auto-completion menu, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to get a list of functions which names start with what has already been entered. Once the name of the function is written completely press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> (on Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) to get a list of its arguments.
- **Function templates**: In Mathematica 9, after typing a function name, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> (on Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) and click on the desired form from the pop-up menu to insert a template with named placeholders for the arguments.

Other useful shortcuts are described in the post [Using the Mathematica front-end efficiently for editing notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8310/66).

- Use palettes in the **Palettes** menu especially when you're beginning.
- In *Mathematica* 8, use the natural input capability of Wolfram Alpha, for example type "= graph 2 x + 1 between 0 and 3" without the quotes and see the command associated with the result.

### Tutorials

- [An elementary introduction to the Wolfram language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction), by Stephen Wolfram
  [Fast introduction for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers)
- [Fundamentals of *Mathematica* Programming](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216) (by Richard Gaylord, great tutorial for an overview of the logic behind *Mathematica*: patterns)
  [Video tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/s?sx=Gaylord) also available
- [Introduction to Mathematica](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/theory/capp2005/Course/hahn/mathematica.pdf) (by Thomas Hahn, another succinct overview of Mathematica)
- [Tutorial Collection](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/) by WRI (lots of extra documentation and examples, available as free PDFs, also available and up-to-date in [**Help** > **Virtual Book**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) in *Mathematica*).
- [Programming Paradigms via Mathematica (A First Course)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/)
- [Mathematica Tutorial: A New Resource for Developers](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/300)
- [Wolfram's Mathematica 101](http://c0de517e.blogspot.fr/2013/10/wolframs-mathematica-101.html)
- http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Software/Downloads/Campus/TrainingMathematicaEnglish.zip
  http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Software/Mathematica/Tutorials/index.html
- [A problem centered approach](http://www.ece.tamu.edu/%7Ehpfister/13lectures.pdf)
- [A beginner's guide to Mathematica](http://mmc.geofisica.unam.mx/edp/Ejemplitos/EcuacionesDiferencialesParciales/Mathematica/ABGMATHs1.pdf)
- http://math.sduhsd.net/MathematiClub/tutorials.htm
- http://www.austincc.edu/mmcguff/mathematica/
- http://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/hnichols/phys303/
- http://www.apam.columbia.edu/courses/ap1601y/ (Introduction to Computational Mathematics and Physics)
- http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/2012/Lectures/ (Applied Mathematics)
  http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/2009/Lectures (path for some lectures in pdf)
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematica
- http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ayg/CS590C/www/mathematica/math.html (Basic tutorial)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430998/mathematica-what-is-symbolic-programming  (What is symbolic programming)
- https://sites.google.com/view/relaxmacro/applications (Mathematica Code to simulate the transition process of a wide range of continuous-time, deterministic, inﬁnite horizon optimization models)
- http://www.physics.umd.edu/enp/jjkelly (An introduction to Mathematica as well as some physics courses)
- [Do you know of any web-based university course that is entirely Mathematica based?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16635/66)
- http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/data/mathematica (Tutorials in Spanish)
- [Mathematica programming](ftp://ftp.pd.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/2009/Lectures/4.MathematicaProgramming.pdf) (some examples of the various programming paradigms that can be used in Mathematica)

### FAQ

- http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm  (FAQ)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica?sort=faq&pagesize=15  (FAQ on Stack Overflow)
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq (FAQ on this site)
- http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/conference98/Lichtblau/SymbolicFAQ.nb (Symbolic FAQ)

### Books

- Stephen Wolfram's [The Mathematica Book](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/) (online, version 5.2), available for free
- [Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) (online) by Leonid Shifrin, available for free
- [Tutorial Collection](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/) by WRI (lots of extra documentation and examples, available as free pdfs, also available and up-to-date in [`Help > Virtual Book`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) in *Mathematica*).
- [Mathematica Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521004.do) by Sal Mangano (O'Reilly, 2010)
- [Mathematica in Action](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica%C2%AE-Action-Problem-Visualization-Computation/dp/0387753664/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662335&sr=1-1) by Stan Wagon (Springer, 2010)
- [Mathematica: A Problem-Centered Approach](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica%C2%AE-Problem-Centered-Approach-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1849962502/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662631&sr=1-1) by Roozbeh Hazrat (Springer, 2010)
- [Mathematica Navigator](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica-Navigator-Mathematics-Statistics-Graphics/dp/0123741645/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662285&sr=1-1) by Heikki Ruskeepaa (Academic Press, 2009)
- The Mathematica GuideBooks (for [Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica-GuideBook-Programming-Michael-Trott/dp/0387942823/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662374&sr=1-1), [Numerics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Mathematica-GuideBook-Numerics-Mathematics/dp/0387950117/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662374&sr=1-2), [Graphics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica-GuideBook-Graphics-Michael-Trott/dp/0387950109/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662374&sr=1-3), [Symbolics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematica-GuideBook-Symbolics-Michael-Trott/dp/0387950206/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334662374&sr=1-4)) by Michael Trott (Springer, 2004-2005)
- [An introduction to programming with Mathematica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521846781) by Paul R. Wellin, Richard J. Gaylord and Samuel N. Kamin (Cambridge University Press, 2005); contains an example of Domain Specific Language (DSL) creation.
- [Mastering Mathematica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122961056) by John W. Gray (Academic Press, 1997)
- [Programming in Mathematica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020185449X) by Roman Maeder (Addison-Wesley Professional, 1997)
- [Programming with Mathematica®: An Introduction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Mathematica-Introduction-Paul-Wellin/dp/1107009464/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359499846&sr=8-1) by Paul Wellin (Cambridge University Press, 2013)
- [Power Programming With Mathematica: The Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007912237X), by David B. Wagner (Mcgraw-Hill, 1997), out of print but scanned copy available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/66).
- http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/01/10/read-up-on-mathematica-in-many-subjects

### Wolfram Websites

**Learn**

- http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/
- http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses (Online video courses, most are free)
  http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/ (Links to videos of past conferences)
- [Slides of seminars](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1;pages_count;search_item_type=21;search_field_1=conference;search_string_1=Free%20Online%20Seminars)
- http://www.youtube.com/user/WolframResearch
- [An elementary introduction to the Wolfram language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction)
  [Fast introduction for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers)
  [Data drop quick reference](https://www.wolfram.com/datadrop/quick-reference/home/)

**Examples**

- http://demonstrations.wolfram.com
- [How To-s](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/HowToTopics.html)
- http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8
  http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9
  http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/
  http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-11/
  http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/new-in-mathematica-10/
- [A plot gallery for Mathematica 9](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4788)
- http://www.wolfram.com/language/

**Resources**

- http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/resources
- http://library.wolfram.com/ (Great amount of resources here)
- http://support.wolfram.com/kb/topic/mathematica (Knowledge base)
- http://www.mathematica-journal.com
- [Help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html)
  [Help > Virtual Book](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html)
- http://www.wolfram.com/support/learn/
- http://www.wolfram.com/books/
- http://reference.wolfram.com

**Blogs**

- http://community.wolfram.com
- http://blog.wolfram.com
- http://blog.wolframalpha.com
- http://blog.stephenwolfram.com
- http://twitter.com/#!/mathematicatip

**Other related sites**

- http://www.mathematica25.com
  SMP
  http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/06/there-was-a-time-before-mathematica
  http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2013/06/SMPHandbook.pdf
- http://www.wolframalpha.com
- [Wolfram Science](http://www.wolframscience.com/): the official site of Stephen Wolfram's New Kind of Science
  [NKS forum](http://forum.wolframscience.com/)
  [Lecture notes from NKS summer schools](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/resources/)
  [Programs from the notes](http://www.wolframscience.com/nks/programs/NKSProgramCDFs.zip)
  [Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=NKS%20/%20Wolfram%20Science&start=1&limit=20&sortmethod=recent)
- http://computerbasedmath.org/
- http://education.wolfram.com (Some interactive basic math courses, useful for curious young people)
- http://www.wolfram.com/webresources.html  (other *Mathematica* related sites)

**Virtual conferences**

- http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/spring-2013
- http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012
- http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2011

**Mathematica one-liner competition**

- http://www.wolfram.com/events/techconf2010/competition.html
- http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/one-liners.html
- http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/mathematica-experts-live-one-liner-competition-2012

**Wolfram technology conferences**

- http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2016
- [2015](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202015), http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015
- [2014](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202014), http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2014
- [2013](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202013), http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2013
- [2012](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202012), http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2012
- [2011](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202011), http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011
- [2010](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference%202010), http://www.wolfram.com/events/techconf2010
- [2009](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=International%20Mathematica%20User%20Conference%202009), [2007](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7046/), [2006](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=2006%20Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference), [2005](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=2005%20Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference), [2004](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=2004%20Wolfram%20Technology%20Conference), [2003](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=2003%20Mathematica%20Developer%20Conference), [2001](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf2001/), [1999](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/), [1998](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/conference98/), [1997](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf97/), [1994](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=1994%20Mathematica%20Developer%20Conference), [1992](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&pages_count=20&search_item_type=21&search_field_1=conference&search_string_1=1992%20Mathematica%20Developer%20Conference)
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/

Comment: Apparently, this is the most edited post by a single person across all of the SE network. You've really done a remarkable job at maintaining it!

Comment: Thanks, maintaining this list is a good way also to keep track of interesting posts on this site that summarize well some aspects of Mathematica.

Comment: Is there a way to download the videos from wolfram.com/broadcast?

Comment: @becko it's not too hard - like downloading YouTube videos, there are various ways. On Mac Safari, I set the user-agent to iPad before going to the page, then Download Linked File: this gets the mp4 download link.   (No Flash for me!)

Comment: @cormullion Got any tricks that work on Windows? I usually download videos from Youtube using a little program called Free Youtube Download. But that doesn't work on wolfram.com/broadcast (except for a few videos at wolfram.com/broadcast that are actually hosted on Youtube).

Comment: @becko I'm not a Windows-er, but perhaps you could investigate switching useragent somehow - there's a tool for the Chrome browser (User Agent Switcher for Chrome) that might work...?

Comment: @cormullion Thanks! I found the option to change the user agent and it works!

Comment: Karl Unterkofler (https://homepages.fhv.at/ku/karl/mma.html) has collected a list of Mathematica timing benchmarks on various hardware platforms (Mac's + PC's). The list also shows an interesting history: from Mathematica version 2.2 up to 8.0.

Comment: In the introduction this link does not work:
Introductory videos of various applications of Mathematica

Comment: This link seems to be broken: http://math.georgiasouthern.edu/math/computer/ABGMATHs1.pdf (in section "Tutorials").

Comment: Ok, I've found another source for the doc and updated the list.

Answer (score 164):

My original post above became too big so I'm splitting it into two posts. The tips and tricks section that I used to keep track of interesting new posts mostly on this site was big so here it is.

Note the tags at the end of each question on this site in order to read related questions.

I'm further dividing this post. See my third answer on [Advanced evaluation, patterns, and neat algorithms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28073/66) below.

### Tips and tricks

**Top posts**

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/66)
  [Programming paradigm change](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45829/66)
- [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/66)
  [Mathematica style guide?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72669/66)
- [General strategies to write big code in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109888/66)
  [Granular versus terse coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110067/66)
- [What is in your *Mathematica* Toolbag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag)

**General tricks**

- [A New Mathematica Programming Style: Functional-Procedural Fusion](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7002/)
- http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html (Ted Ersek's tricks)
  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4557/ (Ted Ersek's tricks as notebooks)
- http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pages/mathematica.html (Szabolcs' tricks)
- http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/tips.html (Verbeia's tricks)
- http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~morrison/Mathematica/ (Tip sheets)
- As pointed out by Mr. Wizard, have a look at the available packages in your install directory for getting new ideas!
- [Tricks of the trade](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=100&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=S3w&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1280&bih=864&q=%22tricks%20of%20the%20trade%22%20site:www.mathematica-journal.com%20filetype:pdf&oq=%22tricks%20of%20the%20trade%22%20site:www.mathematica-journal.com%20filetype:pdf&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.267075.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.QHH8vA5zFGY) in the Mathematica Journal
- [How do I designate arguments in a nested map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15480/66)
- [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/66)
  [Why Mathematica chooses bracket for function arguments over parenthesis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72976/66)
  [Why do Mathematica list indices start at 1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86189/66)
- [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/66)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixAndTensorOperations.html

**Tips for writing faster code**

- [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29349/66)
- http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code
- [Programming for speed](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_10.html)
- [Benchmarking expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22419/66) (timeAvg function)
  [Measuring time complexity of a method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57215/66)
  [Profiling from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7768/66)
- http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/m_performance/m_performance.html
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7005/ (Principles of efficient MM programs, tips for writing fast code)
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/320/  (Generally Efficient Numerics Programming in Mathematica)
- [Writing Efficient Mathematica Code](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/resources/chandler-efficientcode.cdf)
- [Dispatch tables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingSetsOfTransformationRules.html)
  [Using Mathematica's Dispatch](http://mathematicanews.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-mathematicas-dispatch.html)
  [Efficiently extracting an array subset given a separate array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17814/66)
  [How to speed up calculations with large number of replacement rules?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31613/66) (Experimental`OptimizeExpression)
- [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/66)
  [Are there any cases when For[] loops are reasonable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/66)
  [Alternatives to While Loops?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13100/66)
  [Is Table the only functional way to construct nested loops in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19334/66)
  [How to transform Do loop to more efficient codes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21135/66)
  [Replace For-loop with functional code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32404/66)
  [Equivalent Nested Loop Structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35560/66)
  ["do ... while" loop equivalent in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44224/66)
- [Evaluate while external command is being run](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13520/66)
- Use Internal`Bag as a linked list (see links in Data Structures paragraph below)

Reap and Sow

- [Collecting Expressions during Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html)
  Reap and Sow can be used with [StepMonitor](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StepMonitor.html)
- [SelectEquivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245166/884752) (my personal favorite Mathematica function, basically it allows to define classes of equivalence and apply a function on the elements of each class, using Reap and Sow)
  [How would you do a PivotTable in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8099866/884752)
- Reap and Sow can also be used for debugging, see for example how it's used in [ShowIt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15134/66)
- [How to collect result continuously (interruptible calculation) when running parallel calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/313/66)

**Compile**

- [How to compile effectively?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively)
  [How well does Mathematica code exported to C compare to code directly written for C?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/821/66) (Note the function Experimental`OptimizeExpression)
  [Has this implementation of FDM touched the speed limit of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61509/66)
- Note the instruction (<< CompiledFunctionTools`; StringFreeQ[CompilePrint[cf], "MainEvaluate"]) to quickly verify that a compiled function doesn't need calls to external functions, available as from v8.
- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7968/ (Effective Use of the Mathematica Compiler and Code Generation)
  [What kinds of uses of SymbolicC (introduced in Mathematica 8) do you foresee? Are there any neat examples already?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6596/66)
- [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/66)
  [Why is there a huge performance gap using Map with more than 100 List entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54994/66)
- [Shaving the last 50 ms off NMinimize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4700/66)  (Advanced tricks for a very fast Nelder-Mead optimizer)
  [Minimization by Nelder-Mead](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27827/66)
  [Using Apply inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5114/66)
  [Removing calls to MainEvalute when using inlined compiled closures](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13281/66)
- JIT compilation
  [Implementing a function which generalizes the merging step in merge sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/implementing-a-function-which-generalizes-the-merging-step-in-merge-sort)
  [A fast, robust DropWhile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27974/66)
- [Retaining and reusing a one-to-one mapping from a sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19300/66)
- [Is it possible to use Compile on a function with optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19663/66)
- Compiling more functions
  [How can I compile this function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22256/66)
  [Compiling more functions that don't call MainEvaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/66)
  [How to define a complicated function inside the body of Compile?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105815/66)
- [Does Mathematica have a "MATLAB Builder" equivalent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10920/66)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/CodeGeneration.html
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/ref/LibraryGenerate.html
- [Third argument of Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43128/66)
- [CompiledFunctionCall vs. LibraryFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82995/66)
- [Compiling LinearSolve[] or creating a compilable procedural version of it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17774/66)

**Using links to other languages**

- [System interfaces and deployment](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SystemsInterfacesAndDeploymentOverview.html)
- [Faster alternatives for DayOfWeek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/faster-alternatives-for-dayofweek) (Java)
  [Working with Java hashmaps from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42471/66)
- [WSTP](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html)
  [Convert C program using mathlink to WSTP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74131/66)
  [Handling error in WSTP program C/C++](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74176/66)
  [A MathLink tutorial](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174)
  [Mathlink Mode article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v6i3/columns/wagner/contents/63wagner.pdf)
- LTemplate
  [How to simplify writing LibraryLink code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96127/66)
  [Drawing Clifford Attractors in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159668/66)
- [Minimal effort method for integrating C++ functions into Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8438/66)
  [Converting other C++ classes to MTensor in LibraryLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8915/66)
  [How can I use shared libraries in LibraryLink code and ensure Mathematica will find them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34017/66)
  [How to understand shared passing of a MTensor in LibraryLink?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42860/66)
  [Using Boost with CreateLibrary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/using-boost-with-createlibrary)
  [Write C/C++ programs calling Mathematica functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24328/66)
  [Example program for calling Mathematica from C](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32852/66)
  [Returning multiple results from a LibraryLink function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31545/66)
  [Calling Mathematica from Visual Studio - example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33635/66)
  [Which Distributions can be Compiled using RandomVariate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1124/66)
  [Librarylink made easier to use with C++11](https://github.com/pisto/LibraryLink-Cpp11-example)
  [Calling Mathematica from Visual Studio - example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33635/66)
- [How to use C language functions in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65579/66)
- [Mathematica Functions from VBA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23864/66)
- [Linking FORTRAN with Librarylink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5706/66)
- [MATLink](http://matlink.org/), link between Mathematica and Matlab
  [Is it possible to export the equations from Mathematica to MATLAB?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14035/66)
- [Calling IronPython code from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1894/66)
- [JLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html)
  [JLink classes' reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/java/overview-summary.html)
- [ExternalEvaluate for Python fails with Import::nopythonevals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155821/66)

**Packed arrays**

- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/391/  (Packed Arrays)
- [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) (instruction for being warned when a packed array is unpacked)
  [Mathematica memory management for large arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21733/66)
- Avoid mixing integers with real numbers in a list, which would unpack the list and slow computations. For example use 1. instead of 1 if you have to enter manually an entry in a list of reals.
- [Isn't it possible to Pack a SparseArray?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38867/66)

**Debugging**

- [A debug utility to print or extract intermediate data from a program](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15134/66) (ShowIt, a useful variant of Print)
- [The clearest way to represent Mathematica's evaluation sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence)
  [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/66)
  [Is it possible to construct a fullform trace function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160184/66)
- [Debugging memory leaks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6177/66)
  [Profiling memory usage in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418892/884752)
  [Preventing Mathematica from eating up all your memory](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4655) (not a bug but the info can be useful)
  [How to un-eat memory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38842/66)
- [Using the Mathematica debugger, and other interesting possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363520/884752)
  [Debugging Mathematica Code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2245/66)
- [DebugTrace](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html)
- [What are the best practices / most common / idiomatic ways to report errors in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29321/66)
  [How to program a F::argx message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23345/66)
  [How to abort on any message generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/66)
  [Best practices in error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6560116/884752)
  [How to leave function unevaluated programmatically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13837/66)
  [Setting up diagnostic error messages in large Mathematica projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176612/setting-up-diagnostic-error-messages-in-large-mathematica-projects), [Debugging a $RecursionLimit error?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83093/66)
  [Dealing with errors and resuming the code after one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14591/66)
  [Interrupting package evaluation, handling error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19324/66)
  [Prepend Information to Warning Messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/66)
  [Need help with exception handling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31099/66)
  [Error checking and trapping techniques with Throw and Catch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/634/66)
  [Exception/Error handling using returns codes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29283/66)
  [How do I get Mathematica to return a function call unevaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48349/66)
  [Resource management in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1602/66)
- [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) has an integrated debugger and profiler. See here for posts about it on this site: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workbench
  [Inspecting non-variable state from a breakpoint in Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/463/66)
  [workbench: how to see values of global variables during debugging](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44787/66)
- [Mathematica Debuggability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2230/66)
- [Automatically generating a dependency graph of an arbitrary Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/66)
  [Is there an analogue of the Variables command for general expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038/66)
- [Using Java log4j in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96108/66)

**Data Structures**

- [Data structures and efficient algorithms, from Daniel Lichtblau](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/321/)
  [Kd-list, Kd-tree (applied to Gröbner bases)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7619/)
- [Expr Bag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica/6795762#6795762)
  [Internal`Bag inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/66)
  [Efficiently collecting results inside a compiled function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1934/66)
  [Most efficient way of splitting a file into length-prefixed blocks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73728/66)
- [Linked lists](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node525.html)
  [Mathematica “linked lists” and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5095505/884752)
  [Merge-sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/295/66)
  [Variant of the cutting-stock problem in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20743/66)
  The answer of Leonid is a reference on the topic: [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/66)
  [Searching linked lists that contain lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32134/66)
- [Efficient circular buffer?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18078/66)
- [Efficient priority queues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31968/66)
- BTree
  [Using Memoization with a Mutable Object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4654/66)
  [How to speed up Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13160/66)
  [How to make Huffman coding by using tree representation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47873/66)
  [What is the fastest way to maintain a large set of expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26637/66)
  [Generating an ordered list of pairs of elements from ordered lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10445/66)

Objects

- [How to create strong types?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4636/66)
  [How to implement FittedModel like objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15945/66)
  [How can one define a custom data object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2590/66)
- [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/66)
  [Implementing a dictionary data structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31932/66)
  [Is there HashTable structure in Wolfram Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392007/is-there-hashtable-structure-in-wolfram-mathematica)
  [Is there a method to enumerate the keys/values of System`Utilities`HashTable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26669/66)
  A usage example in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7506/66) of Oleksandr R. or in the answer to the post
  [How can you give a Module a context and have its local variables and Modules belong to that context?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/586/66)
  [What's fastest way of defining 10^5 down values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13635/66)
  [Return a Part by Reference? (For accessing hierarchical / structured data)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13643/66)
- [Once more on object orientation in Mathematica: does it have to be so hard?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869/66)
  [Builder pattern for complex objects construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31796/66)
  [How can I implement object oriented programming in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6497/66)
- [MTools](https://github.com/faysou/MTools), an open-source package for OOP from the author of this answer
- [OOP applied to manipulate](http://12000.org/my_notes/object_based_in_mathematica/v1.html)
- [Question about designing a particular data structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8491/66)
- [Code Readability and Object-Oriented Code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8690/66)
- [Polymorphism and the pattern-matcher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33919/66)
- [Inheritance in Mathematica using pattern matching on UpValues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43972/66)
- [How to implement the Observer design pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47659/66)
- http://www.objectica.net/Documentation6/guide/ReferenceGuide.html (non free, but still can give some inspiration)

Traversal of an expression

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/66)
- [How to perform a breadth-first traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209/66)
- [Determining all possible traversals of a tree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5753/66)
- [Uses for MapAll (//@)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747742)
  myHold examples with MapAll ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=myhold),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwolfram-mathematica%5D%20myhold))
- [Can a Trie be implemented efficiently?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/441/66)
- [Concatenate strings from different levels of list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17696/66)

Graphs

- [GraphUtilities](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GraphUtilities/tutorial/GraphUtilities.html)
- [How to play with Facebook data inside Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11673/66)

**Optional Values**

- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options)
- [What are the benefits of switching from Rule and /. to OptionsPattern[] and OptionValue in a large application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6617511/884752)
- [How to avoid collision between optional arguments and options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-optional-arguments-and-options)
- [Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/can-a-function-be-made-to-accept-a-variable-amount-of-inputs)
- [Dealing with nested options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/dealing-with-nested-options)
- [Evaluation of OptionValue[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18674/66)
- [Custom functions by delegating options in a specific way and using core functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697/66) (withOptionConfiguration)
- [Specifying optional arguments with variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29013/66)
- [Is there any way to define pure functions with optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29206/66)
  [Is it possible to separately call the default value of a variable which isn't at the end of the sequence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29208/66)
- [Why doesn't Mathematica use uniform criteria for validating Options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17358/66)
  [How to check the validity of an option value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116623/66)
- [How to inherit options by scoping?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43222/66)
- [How to make a function with its own options as well as passing options to other functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43088/66)
- [Using a held option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65835/66)
- [Writing functions with "Method" options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111666/66) (Interesting answer on parsing a grammar of options)

**Accessing data in different ways**

- [Cases[data,Colon[key,_]] vs. Cases[data,key:_] toward XPath, XQuery](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3916/66)
- [Emulating R data frame getters with UpValues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9702/66)
  [Creating a R DataFrame like construct in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19136/66)
  [How to achieve Set+Part like behaviour in custom Set function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19897/66)
- [The gap between MapAt and ReplacePart for 2D data tables with headers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9269/66)
- [Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29334/66)
  [Data Table Manipulation in Mathematica: Step 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8240943/884752)
  [How can a big table be treated as a database?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11151/66)
- [Path queries for tree-structured data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3325/66)
- [Splitting up delimited data in lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2150/66)
  [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/66) (dynamicPartition)
  [Splitting a list by specifying section headers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11973/66)
- [Accessing list elements by name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22599/66)

Association/Dataset

- [How to make use of Associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52393/66)
  [Normal // Association // Dataset workaround for some user query operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54843/66)
  [Can't get Append to append a record (association) to a dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55716/66)
  [How can I save a Manipulate's control settings to a dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56349/66)
  [V10's Operator Forms - what are they good for?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/66)
  [What is the natural way of using Dataset to get a FittedModel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56110/66)
  [Dataset: get number of levels and elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56983/66)
  [Is there a comprehensive list of functions with operator forms?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60045/66)
  [Converting structured data to a dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55307/66)
  [How can I add a column into a existing Dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51472/66)
  [GroupBy several keys while keeping the Dataset as a Table (List of Associations)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57016/66)
  [Learning Resources for Data Science in the Wolfram Language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56009/66) (many usage examples of List/Association/Dataset)
  [SQL-like computation on Dataset: Aggregate function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71318/66)
  [Is there a faster way to Map an Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/66)
  [Difference between Association and Dispatch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69291/66)
  [Changing Values in an Association using Map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55494/66) (Answer on Immutability)
  [Filtering Query Nested Data (Dataset and Association)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69045/66)
  [Is there an idiomatic way to determine whether an `Association` is a subset of another?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88667/66)
  [Visualizing Type System Operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89080/66)
  [Struggling to understand Query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98181/66)
  [Reshaping associations, generalization of GroupBy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107399/66)

**Rules and replacement (the backbone of *Mathematica*, more advanced)**

- [Where definitions are stored](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html)
- [What is the distinction between DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues)

**Getting ideas from Lisp**

- [Structure and interpretation of computer programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), [Common Lisp The Language](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/clm.html), [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html), [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) ...
- [repl.it](http://repl.it/#:languages) has an online interpreter for Scheme with some examples.
- [Is there a Mathematica/Lisp link?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4203/66)
- Other functional languages : [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org), [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/), [Clojure](http://clojure.org/), [Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/), [F#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/fsharp/), [Maude](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/maude1/manual/maude-manual-html/maude-manual_0.html) ...
- [FAQ on functional programming](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/faq.html)

**Memoization/Caching**

- The answer of Leonid is a reference on the topic: [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/66)
- [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/66)
- [Avoid repeated calls to Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781981/avoid-repeated-calls-to-interpolation/7784989) (Interesting answers and links about caching values and expressions)
- [Function that caches when it returns unevaluated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/588/66)
- [Why is there no PositionFunction in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/66)
- [Built-in Mathematica data: are they cached? how to speed up the loading?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1119/66)
- [Memoization with pure functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85750/66)

**Undocumented features**

- [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/66)
  [Documentation of the frequently-used functions in the context of Internal` and Compile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82790/66)
  [Items known by CurrentValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/66)
- [How can one find undocumented options or option values in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/66)
- [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/66)
- [How do you convert a string containing a number in C scientific notation to a Mathematica number?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/66)
- [What is the complete list of valid FrontEnd Packet types?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13451/66)
- [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/66)
- [How can I manipulate TemporalData?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30712/66)
- [How to work with Experimental`NumericalFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/66)
- [Full documentation for AppearanceElements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46792/66)
- [How to create internally optimized expression for computing with high WorkingPrecision?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25432/66)
- [What are all the named Mathematica styles?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29527/66)
- [How to create expanding summary boxes like the ones displayed for InterpolatingFunction, NearestFunction, etc.?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77658/66)
- [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/66)
- [Monte Carlo integration with random numbers generated from a Gaussian distribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45133/66)

**IDEs and packages**

- [How to install the Wolfram Workbench plugin into Eclipse Kepler or Neon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18183/66)
  [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench)
  [Managing formatted usage messages in Wolfram Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3941/66)
  [Creating cross-version compatible documentation with Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28316/66)
  [Renaming projects in Wolfram Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65886/66)
  [Recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26174/66)
  [How to setup Team Development for a Mathematica project?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5789/66)
- [Open-source IntelliJ IDEA plugin to support Mathematica development](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/66)
- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/how-to-distribute-mathematica-packages-as-paclets)
  [How to properly handle mutual imports of multiple packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10306/66) 
  [What's the difference between these two ways of specifying dependent packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13958/66)
  [Second argument of BeginPackage with nested package loading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115502/66)
  [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/66)
  [What are recommended guidelines for developing packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/290/66)
  [How to unload automatically loaded packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1487/66)
  [How can I dynamically get a file whenever it is saved in Workbench?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7455/66)
  [How to work with Application Project files in Wolfram Workbench?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14339/66)
  [What is a "Paclet"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1660/66)

**Mathematica functions and environment**

- [How to specify Mathematica as a programming language?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/270/66)
  http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html
  [Where can I access documentation for old versions of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87085/66)
  http://12000.org/my_notes/compare_mathematica/index.htm
  [How to get complete Documentation Center graph of guide pages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8505/66)
  [Automated testing for compatibility with older Mathematica versions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2047/66)
  [Integrating notebooks to Mathematica's documentation center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6574710/884752) (Using Wolfram Workbench is easier for building a help but the answer is still interesting)
  [List of dangerous functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364/66)
  [What are all the named Mathematica styles?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29527/66)
- [How does Plot work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346/66)
  [How to implement the sample-point process like the built-ins of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88299/66)
  [How to examine the structure of Graphics objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32716/66)
  [Symbolic derivatives are being calculated numerically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29329/66)
  [Embed Code Into Image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25759/66)
- [How does Mathematica calculate integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111946/66)
- [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/66)
  [How to get grid lines at all (log) tick marks in Version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54613/66)
- [How can I set up a versioning system within a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6435/66)
  [Is there a notebook autosave frequency configuration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13997/66)
  [Are there suitable versioning systems for Mathematica notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11258/66)
- [How to find a specific error message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14792/66)
- [The Joy of Tagging: Manipulating and Mining Notebooks in Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7246/)
  [How to programmatically mark and then select a subset of input cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90142/66)
- [Programmatic formatting for Mathematica code - possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2809/66)
  [Syntax highlighting for your own functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1446/66)
  [Customizing syntax highlighting for private cell styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1315/66)
  [Special Mathematica Cell to work with R code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16657/66)
- [Is it possible to improve Mathematica's auto-completion feature?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16599/66)
- [Creating a notebook that has cells of a certain style password protected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17563/66)
  [Advanced typesetting](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8010/)
  [Resources for beautiful Mathematica Stylesheets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5846/66)
  [Some tutorials on formatting notebook for exporting to pdf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9437/66)
  [What options and settings can be used to create print quality typeset documents with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108553/66)
- [Adding a label to an expression result](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17121/66)
  [How to fold output cells by default?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29258/66)
- [Automatic e-mail/text message when a calculation has finished?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30167/66)
  [Keep MathKernel Running In Background - Speed Up Execution Time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23217/66)
- [Simpler input for the new unit support](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15338/66)
- [Quality of random numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3208/66)
- [Will Mathematica install and run on Raspberry Pi computer?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11761/66)
- [Scheduling Mathematica scripts to run from a command line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38888/66)
- [How to keep $FrontEnd options from resetting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38556/66)
- [How do I add new menuitems to menus?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/907/66)
- [Mathematica color schemes for the colorblind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20851/66)
  [Is there an easy way to use Matteo Niccoli's perceptual color maps for 2D plots in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64513/66)
- [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337/66)
- [Are there any tutorials on version 10 notebook templating and report generation? Are there missing docs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54768/66)
- [Handling Kernel start. What is a full initialization stack and what place the Autoload has there?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110243/66)

Comment: Now this is really useful, big +1. The better we categorize all these resources, the more effective this page will be.

Comment: This could be the Table of Contents of *Mathematica*.SE.

Comment: This is such a fabulous resource, thank you for taking the time to compile it.

Comment: Hi, @faysou, I'd like to see "Data structures and efficient algorithms, from Daniel Lichtblau", but this resources is not available anymore. Do you have a copy?

Comment: @matheorem no I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: The Data Structures presentation is back online.

Answer (score 59):

Third part of my collection of links, dedicated to advanced evaluation, pattern matching and neat algorithms (which is quite arbitrary but contains a lot of interesting Q&As in my opinion).

**Advanced evaluation of expressions**

- Non standard evaluation allows to work on the symbols of an expression before they get evaluated.

  Here's how I represent myself Mathematica's evaluation: consider a function/tree f[a,b]. Without any particular attribute for f the leafs/arguments will be evaluated before the parent f. With f having a HoldAll attribute you don't evaluate the leafs but go directly in the evaluation of f. a and b will be evaluated as soon as they are used in a function that doesn't hold again their evaluation. For example

  ```
  f[a_,b_]:= a Hold[b]; 
  f[2^2,2^2] (* returns 4 Hold[4] *)

  SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];  
  f[2^2,2^2] (* returns 4 Hold[2^2] *)
  ```

  You can also see with the above example that SetDelayed (:=) acts like a With, ie it can insert a value inside a held expression.

  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html
  [Preventing evaluation of *Mathematica* expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions)
  [Hold any argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255999/hold-any-argument)
  [How can I hold UpValues but evaluate other expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8558/66)
  [Symbolic computations with already assigned variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16933/66)
  [How to pass a symbol name to a function with any of the Hold attributes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651/66)
  [Pure function with attributes of arbitrary number of arguments: Is it possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/66)
- [*Mathematica* Language Structure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LanguageStructureOverview.html)
- [*Mathematica* Internals: A Tutorial](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4683)
  [The evaluation process](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_3.html)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html
  [List manipulation to build a functional expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20328/66)
  [How does Mathematica determine that an evaluation should be terminated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29343/66)
  [What are all the "magic" Symbols in the Mathematica language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121981/66)
- [Some notes on internal implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)
  [The Internals of the Wolfram System](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheInternalsOfTheWolframSystemOverview.html)
  [Algorithm used by IsomorphicGraphQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13944/66)
- [What is the complete sequence of evaluations/transformations from submitting a cell to actual evaluation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11370/66)
  [\$PreRead, \$Pre, \$Post, \$PrePrint](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_38.html)
- [Robby Villegas, Working with Unevaluated Expressions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/) (Advanced resource about the evaluation process)
  [Update a function avoiding infinite recursion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21789/66) ([Villegas-Gayley technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/884752))
  [Understanding Villegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/66)
- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)
  [A speed comparison between Module, Block and With](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8228/66)  (Still, Module is what users use most of the time)
  [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/66)
  [What does Internal`InheritedBlock do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/66)
  [How safe is the use of Block and Internal`InheritedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25673/66)
  [What is the purpose of Internal`LocalizedBlock?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71881/66)
  [What are the scoping rules for function parameters shadowing System` symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27839/66)
  [Constructing symbol definitions for With](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/66)
  [Using With to scope over pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34345/66)
  [Module variable scoping in Scheduled Tasks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3807/66)

  [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/66)
  [StringReplace, ReplaceAll and Rule interact in a bizarre way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46611/66)
- [What are some advanced uses for Block?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11579/66)
  [How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/66)
  [Safely nesting RuleDelayed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6995/66)
- [Metaprogramming in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/metaprogramming-in-mathematica)
- [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/66)
- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/66)
  [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/66)
  [Is it possible to replicate the "magic" of OptionPatterns[] with DynamicModule's local variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10627/66)
  [How does MakeBoxes handle an n-ary operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20643/66)
  [How to inject an evaluated expression into a held expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2678/66) (Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation trick, RuleCondition)
  [How to pass a list of arguments into HoldAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21830/66)
  [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880/66)
  [Passing a joined list of symbols for Module or Block to treat as its own local symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34873/66)
  [Replacing parts of a held expression with held parts of another expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43095/66)
- Expression parsing examples
  [Converting StringJoin to StringForm inside Hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40628/66)
  [How to write a function to remove comments from a .m source file preserving formatting such as line wrapping reasonably?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/how-to-write-a-function-to-remove-comments-from-a-m-source-file-preserving-form/)
  [How to write a function-defining function which stores the function arguments in a stack?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2206/66)
  [Is there a Mathematica API for the functions.wolfram site?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/911/66)
  [Function that counts the number of arguments of other functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7040/66)
  [Using MatchQ (or other means) to parse an expression using sums of COS or SIN correctly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30588/66)
  [Automatically generating a dependency graph of an arbitrary Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/4345#4345)

  [Programmatic formatting for Mathematica code - possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/programmatic-formatting-for-mathematica-code-possible/2810#2810)
- [Functional style using lazy lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists)
  [Tally repeated evaluation of function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18813/66)
  [File-backed lists/variables for handling large data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data) (Lazy evaluation of streams)
  [Lazy lists of Tuples and Subsets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9554/66)
- [How to use pattern matching to assign values to Subscript[f,x_]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9526/66)
- [Implementing a safe ValueQ that does not evaluate its argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/66)
- [Convert an expression to a Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10067/66)
  [Nested definition: How can I define a function with a passed-in expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086/66)
- [How to avoid nested With[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10432/66)
  [Comparing LetL and Module efficiency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11577/66)
- [Do people actually use UpValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11435/66)
  [Upvalues, TagSet and UpSet, what's the difference, when should a use each?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18410/66)
  [How to implement dual numbers in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13912/66)
  [Make mathematica treat $e_i^2$ as numeric](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16976/66)
  [How to differentiate formally?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375/66)
- [Currying with Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494/884752)
  [Going full functional (Haskell style)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23818/66)
- [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/66) (Vanishing function)
- [SetAttributes[f,Flat]: Why the order dependence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/304/66)
  [The Flat Attribute, Unevaluated and the Evaluation Process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29300/66)
  [Orderless pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71463/66)
- Spelunking
  [What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/66)
  [How to see which arguments are passed into a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43120/66)
- [How does Return work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/66)
  [What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/66)
  [FoldWhile and FoldWhileList](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/foldwhile-and-foldwhilelist)
- [Tail call optimization in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481301/884752)
  [What tools can help in realizing tail recursion?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21746/66)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/66)
  [How to name a variable with the value of another variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56419/66)
- [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/66)
- [How to find the name of the current function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20618/66)
- [Does pass-by-value affect the performance of function calls?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20865/66)
- [Comparing Mathematica expressions like diff](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24418/66)
- [What is the fastest way to get a list of subexpressions and their positions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26511/66)
- [Resource management in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1602/66)
- [How to pass a list of arguments into HoldAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21830/66)
  [Dynamic Programming with delayed evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27271/66)
- [Multiplying expressions within a list of pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28064/66)
  [Using Through to evaluate complex expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28056/66)
- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/66)
  [Scoping in assigning a derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/66)
- [Getting a usable expression tree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29565/66)
- [Call Functions From File Without Modifying Context (Sandbox)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29779/66)
- [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/704/66)
  [when is f@g not the same as f[g]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/66)
  [When should I use Apply (or Function) and when @@ (or &)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33794/66)
- [Constructing functions with variable number of output arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/314/66)
  [Alternative to overloading Set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1162/66)
- [What are the cool kids talking about when they use ##&[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78910/66)
  [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/66)
- [How to create symbols from strings and set values for them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/66)
- [What's the difference between Inactive and HoldForm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54556/66)
- [Is it possible to reference "self" from a pure function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96220/66)
- [How can one manually change the rule ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106068/66)
- [Permanently extending the behaviour of functions (like decorators)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155567)

**[Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html) matching**

A pattern is a way to quickly describe the structure of expressions and do computations on them, using [`/.`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) or [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) for example.

- [Some examples](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_7.html)
  Much more elaborate: a [Texas Hold'em](https://github.com/smangano/Mathematica-Texas-Holdem) package by Sal Mangano
- [Rules, pattern and functions](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/chapterNode5.html), one of the chapter of Leonid Shifrin's book.
  [Demistifying rules](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i4/features/blachman/contents/DemystifyingRules.pdf)
- [Where in the documentation can I find a list of function argument types?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10175/66)
  [How can I type-check the arguments of a Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33884/66)
- [Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/66)
- [Using ?NumericQ to Affect Order of Evaluation](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820)
  [Is it possible to use the LevenbergMarquardt algorithm for fitting a black-box residual function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1954/66)
- [Convert boolean test function to pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18054/66)
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6999/ (Inside the Mathematica pattern matcher)
- [Is there an open source implementation of Mathematica-the-language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4454/66)  (Some interesting links to papers about pattern matching, [1](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_131/Kutsia-UNIF03.pdf),[2](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_342/1996-11-01-A.pdf),[3](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/tkutsia/papers/Kutsia-Marin-WIL.pdf),[4](http://http.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/mma.review.pdf))
  [MockMMA](http://www.norvig.com/ltd/test/mma-match.dylan)
  [Mathador](https://github.com/poeschko/Mathador)
  [Mathematica as a normal programming language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15507/66)
  [Mathematica for Computer Scientists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7591/66)
- [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/66) (Mr. Wizard also gives many links to interesting answers illustrating the same point)
- [How to match a pattern with a pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2778/66)
  [How to generally match, unify and merge patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2918/66)
  [Pattern matching a pattern with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17892/66)
- [Semantica](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/features/harris/), a package for using semantic patterns (f[(2 n_)] for example)
- [How do I perform string matching and replacements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/66)
  [Working with string patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html)
  [Counting the number of instances of one sub-string within a given string within a lower- and upper-bound gap of a second sub-string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46096/66)
- [Placement of Condition /; expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/533/66)
  [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/66)
  [Use of StringExpression as argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32112/66)
  [Quick way to use conditioned patterns when defining multi-argument function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52057/66)
- [Assessing argument type in set delayed function definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9356/66)
  [How to Combine Pattern Constraints and Default Values for Function Arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/66)
- [ForEach in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160216/884752)
- [Why does the name of a pattern affect the result of a transformation rule?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10309/66)
- [Conflict with variables in pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78858/66)
- [How to match expressions with a repeating pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045/66)
- [Is it possible to specify a context-sensitive, "depth-agnostic" rewrite rule?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11331/66)
- [Change variables in differential expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9351/66)
- [Transforming XML](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/XML/tutorial/TransformingXML.html)
  [Extract information from HTML using Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809812/884752)
  [How to manipulate web pages on Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2362/66)
  [Extract information from HTML using CSS selectors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71914/66)
- [Replacements/Substitutions in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14994/66) (\$Assumptions)
- [Position function not always returning an answer even with no apparent problems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907/66)
- [How can I ensure that I am constructing patterns in the most efficient way possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/237/66)
- [How can I find these patterns' signatures?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16871/66)
- [replacement rules from a pattern and a matching expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17660/66)
- [Position of a pattern-matched part of an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19022/66)
  [Select cases from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46472/66) (ReplaceList)
- [Patternmatching sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19692/66)
- [Using patterns in pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3174/66)
- [The difference between 0. and 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6994/66)
- [“Strange” behavior of Rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24860/66)
- [f[arg1, arg2,...,argN] vs. f[{arg1, arg2,...,argN}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/66)
  [A function that accepts a pair or a list of pairs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/66)
  [Alternatives pattern in a function definition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44081/66)
  [How to distinguish between lists and values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2493/66)
  [Vanishing patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/66)
- [Get a "step-by-step" evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/66)
  [Interactively inspecting parts of an object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70190/66)
- [How to do Cases with multiple related patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42582/66)
- [How to match a cyclically repeating sequence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43801/66)
- [How to define a recursive pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85683/66)
  [Convert recursive RegularExpression to StringExpression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73247/66)
  [Pattern match for nested Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61574/66)
- [How to enlarge Mathematica's knowledge about certain functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33251/66)
- [Calling Table with custom iterator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6949/66)

**Neat algorithms**

- [Mathematica Minecraft](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19669/66)
  [How to create word clouds?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2334/66)
  [How can I use Mathematica's graph functions to cheat at Boggle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5387/66)
  [Performance tuning for game solving (peg solitaire | senku)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6704/66)
  [Factorisation diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11657/66)
  [Happy 2K prime question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7132/66)
  [Simulating Theatre puzzle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16458/66)
  [How can I generate this "domain coloring" plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7275/66)
  [Tiling a square](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6822/66)
  [Generating visually pleasing circle packs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40334/66)
  [Circuit drawing in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8614/66)
  [Detecting patterns of black and white stones on a 2D board](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46631/66)
  [How to build a bvh (a motion capture file format) player in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60292/66)
- [How to draw Fractal images of iteration functions on the Riemann sphere?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15047/66)
  [Generating a Sierpinski carpet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22052/66)
  [Speeding up this fractal-generating code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104/66)
- [Explain a Mathematica winning one-liner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17232/66)
- [How can this confetti code be improved to include shadows and gravity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1900/66)
  [How to create animated snowfall?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16881/66)
- [xkcd-style graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11350/66)
  [xkcdConvert routines perform slower in Mathematica 9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17272/66)
  http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/
  [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/66)
- [How to improve the performance of solutions to Project Euler (#39)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10001/66)
  [How to find palindromic numbers (Project Euler #4)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9926/66)
- Image processing
  [Help find a bright object on Mars!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11819/66)
  [How can I find Waldo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8479058/884752)
  [QR Code in shopping cart handle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26268/66)
  [Playing with Matrix falling code in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20557/66)
  [Image segmentation and object separation in 3D using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31997/66)
  [Artistic image vectorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8507/66)
  [DumpsterDoofus's captivating generative art](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64492/66)
- [How to express trigonometric equation in terms of of given trigonometric function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/434/66)
  [How do I introduce a new variable in a trigonometric equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11178/66)
  [Checking if two trigonometric expressions are equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7473/66)
- [Efficiently generating n-D Gaussian random fields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4829/66)
  [Distribution of random points in 3D space to simulate the Crab Nebula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20882/66)
- [How to improve this code for solving the "Mr.S and Mr.P" puzzle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13898/66)
  [Efficient code for the Ten True Sentences puzzle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17377/66)
  [Mathematica Implementations of the Random Forest algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19285/66)
  [Soft-Match String Comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20608/66)
  [Gram-Schmidt Process for Polynomials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22040/66)
  [How to determine the center and radius of a circle given some points in 3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16209/66)
  [Counting multiplications (complexity function)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25760/66)
  [Insert $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$, $($, $)$ into $123456789$ to make it equal to $100$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15021/66)
  [Higher order SVD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5879/66)
  [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/66)
  [Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32293/66)
  [Solving a time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21751/66)
  [Efficient backtracking with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7557/66)
  [Determine frequency of oscillations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47917/66)
  [Alternative ways to implement a triangular recursion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1691/66)
  [Implementation of smoothing splines function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33206/66)
- Position
  [Efficiently finding the positions of a large list of targets in another, even larger list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21820/66)
  [Looking for a way to insert multiple elements into multiple positions simultaneously in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/66)
  [Efficient way of identifying the indices of first occurrences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38793/66)
- Duplicates
  [Deleting quasi-duplicates from large list efficiently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42599/66)
  [Delete duplicate elements from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2419/66)
  [Ordering function with recognition of duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21458/66)
  [How to get list of duplicates when using DeleteDuplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37936/66)
  [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/66)
  [Removing elements from a list which appear in another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/66)
- Map/Thread
  [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/66)
  [Map a function across a list conditionally](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9784/66)
  [Map-Thread-Through-Apply a list of functions onto a list of (lists of) values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/66)
  [Thread over list in different levels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/66) 
  [Thread over a nested list top to bottom until non-list elements are found](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17291/66) 
  [How can I make threading more flexible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/66)
  [How to make MapAt work with Span?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6114/66)
- Flatten
  ["Unflattening" a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30405/66)
  [Transpose uneven lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3643/66)
- List manipulations
  [Finding a subsequence in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/66)
  [How to select minimal subsets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8154/66)
  [Optimising 2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17734/66)
  [Efficiently extracting an array subset given a separate array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17814/66)
  [Quick multiple selections from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19223/66)
  [How to Derive Tuples Without Replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1921/66)
  [Need help coding/creating a recursive list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21281/66) (FoldList)
  [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/66)
  [Instruct a Table to only evaluate until a condition is fulfilled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24497/66)
  [How do I replace a missing value in a column with the value immediately above throughout a table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26723/66)
  [Sort+Union on a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27274/66)
  [How to generalize and speed up this program?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31023/66)
  [How do I obtain an intersection of two or more list of lists conditioned on the first element of each sub-list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16450/66)
  [Vlookup function as Excel in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18721/66)
  [Partitioning a list of numbers the Mathematica way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36867/66)
  [How to pick increasing numbers from the list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38325/66)
  [How to replace an element in a list based on the value of the next element?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38472/66)
  [How to partition a list in a specific way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38530/66)
  [Nest , Fold ... is there an extension for more than 2 arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39476/66)
  [List comprehension in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37954/66) (similar to Python)
  [Select a repeated element in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40317/66)
  [Fast method for combining two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41003/66)
  [Discrete Convolution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1172/66)
  [Shuffle product of two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/66)
  [Is there a function which instantly tells you whether an element is part of a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43541/66)
  [Sort data after specific ordering (ascending/descending) in multiple columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2934/66)
  [Total by a criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61655/66)

Comment: That's incredible! Thanks for keeping up a great work, this is very useful for all of us, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, you're the hero of many of these posts.

Comment: @Leonid I've collected some of your answers where you use a parsing approach, if there are other such posts could you please add them to the list ?

Comment: Thanks. It's good that this technique is now systematically represented here, I think it is an important one. I have added [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/4345#4345), and my answer for the code formatter question (since in a sense formatter is also an expression parser, and in fact a pretty sophisticated one), which are the only ones that comes to mind right now.

Comment: I find the most difficult part of Mathematica is controlling evaluation (because there isn't just a single way to do it), and I think it's very important for the future of Mathematica, where macros (or code for rewriting code) is the horizon.  The post above is extremely valuable.

Answer (score 42):

I highly recommend examining the included packages under your *Mathematica* installation directory:

> \AddOns\ExtraPackages
>
> \AddOns\LegacyPackages
>
> \AddOns\Packages
>
> \AddOns\Applications

You can also find examples of good practice, framework guidelines, and insider methods in the presentations from various *Mathematica* conferences.  A mere sampling:

[1999 *Mathematica* Developer Conference](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/)

[2003 Mathematica Developer Conference](http://www.wolfram.com/news/events/devconf2003/notebooks.html)

[2007 Wolfram Technology Conference](http://www.wolfram.com/news/events/techconf2007/presentations.html)

[Many, *many* more.](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/)

Answer (score 38):

Besides the documentation, which I find very helpful, I also like the following resources:

- The [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/) is a fantastic resource, where you can draw up previously successful programs and learn some best practices. Their utility has varied, but I've certainly learned a lot by seeing great code in practice.
- In a similar vein, I also follow the ['Wolfram Blog'](http://blog.wolfram.com/). It's not all universally relevant for my own interests, but following it on Twitter is a good way to dip in here and there.
- Finally, as a new user, I also draw on the [Mathematica Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521004.do) for some nifty examples.

As noted above, however, I normally use the documentation and look through examples of uses, as that's my best way of learning.

Comment: +1 for the cookbook but I agree with @Nasser on the readability of the demonstrations (plus, doing everything in one giant code block as demonstrations seem to organize things is probably not going to scale very well for anything nontrivial)

Answer (score 30):

In my opinion, rules and pattern matching are central to mastering *Mathematica*. I strongly recommend Demystifying Rules by Nancy Blachman published in *The Mathematica Journal*, Volume 8, Issue 4, for a solid grounding in this area. It is available on-line at [The *Mathematica* Journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i4/features/blachman/contents/DemystifyingRules.pdf)

Answer (score 29):

For neat tips and tricks, there is a daily tip posted to the [MathematicaTip](http://twitter.com/MathematicaTip) twitter page.

Comment: This is a pretty good resource. It has lots of small, easy to digest snippets.

Answer (score 28):

The Mathematica GuideBook by Michael Trott always gives me lots of inspirations. Beside of it (and other places been mentioned above), I like exploring the SystemFiles folder. Some interesting tricks (especially about interface and FrontEnd) are hiding there.

Comment: The SystemFiles suggestion is a good one. Do you have any particular examples to share?

Comment: @Verbeia Some undocumented things can be learned from the system files. such as `"SyntaxColoringReasons"` for `CurrentValue` which can be seen in WhyTheColoring.nb (`Dynamic[CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], "SyntaxColoringReasons"]]`), system fonts classification which can be seen in UnicodeFontMapping.tr, some inappropriate converting when import GBK encoded Chinese text can be corrected by manipulating CP936.m, etc.

Answer (score 26):

The ['Mathematica GuideBook'](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/) series by Michael Trott has tons of good examples that go much further than typical 'toy-examples'. I found it a very valuable and thorough ressource for learning the ins and outs of the Mathematica language.

Answer (score 26):

Nobody's mentioned the packages that come with Mathematica.  There's a heap of great coding examples in there, especially the later packages.

Answer (score 26):

Fourth fork of the list of links.

**Manipulate/Dynamic**

- [Using Refresh[..] with TrackedSymbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21625/66)
- [Got Manipulate?](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7338/) (Seminar slides)
  [Manipulate secrects revealed](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8332/)
- [What is the equivalent of a prototypical Manipulate in lower level functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4878/66)
  [Selective evaluation of blocks of code in a Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33303/66)
- [Understanding CDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/66)
- [How to modularize custom controls for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5335/how-to-modularize-custom-controls-for-manipulate)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html (See last paragraph)
- [Question about collections of custom GUI controls for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/question-about-collections-of-custom-gui-controls-for-mathematica)
- [How to execute a function each time the slider is dragged?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16171/66)
  [How can I make controls have Button-like behaviour?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33346/66)
- [How can I effectively performance-profile Dynamics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8045/66)
- [Multiplayer game in Mathematica: how to communicate between kernels?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44027/66)
- [Mathematica Manipulate with macros AND variable number of controls (persistence desired)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8919/66)
- [How to wrap this dynamic code inside a Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10093/66)
- [For[] or While[] can't be used inside Manipulate[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10753/66)
- [Manipulate with explicit updates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13063/66)
- [Wrapping EventHandler by Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13440/66)
- [Generalized input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html) (look at Interpretation)
- [What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17112/66)
- [How to anchor a Pane's scroll position to the bottom?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1745/66)
- [How to visualize/edit a big matrix as a table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/66)
- [Button evaluation inside DynamicModule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29129/66)
- [Altering layout and sizing of Manipulate controls?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29002/66)
- [Unexpected Setter Bar Behavior when Manipulate Nested in Dynamic Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29459/66)
- [How can I use Dynamic to run a script when a new file is added to a directory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31758/66)
- [Using list elements in TrackedSymbols for Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32503/66)
- [Evaluation order control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19809/66)
- [How to make slider in/visible in Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40037/66)
- [How to visualize the structure of this dynamic programming code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39871/66)
- [Slider resistance and Play-Pausing with Manipulate, TabView, and attempt an granular TrackedSymbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40559/66)
  [trouble with Dynamic range in SetterBar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41735/66)
- [How to save Manipulate bookmarks permanently?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17951/66)
- [Writing a simple application: interactive quiz for multiplication table practice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44979/66)
- [Dynamically Updating Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45948/66)
- [How can I create an advanced grid interface?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21117/66)
- [Alternative updating of a dynamic expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21598/66)
  [How to anchor a Pane's scroll position to the bottom?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1745/66)
- [How to Initiate a queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19174/66)
  [Evaluation order control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19809/66)
- [How to avoid an expensive subset of a Manipulate computation when dependent variables have not changed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40066/66)
  [Slider resistance and Play-Pausing with Manipulate, TabView, and attempt an granular TrackedSymbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40559/66)
  [OOP applied to manipulate](http://12000.org/my_notes/object_based_in_mathematica/v1.html)
- [Event driven GUI](http://www.12000.org/my_notes/event_driven_GUI_with_Manipulate/event_driven_manipulate.htm)
- [Using Refresh[..] with TrackedSymbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21625/66)
  [What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17112/66)
- [SaveDefinitions considered dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous)

**Palettes**

- [Can I easily post images to this site directly from Mathematica? (Yes!)](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/66)
- [A palette of accumulated expertise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9752/66)
- [For Sale! Three potentially useful palettes](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/771/66)
- [What are the most common (usual) ways to make palettes with non-trivial functionality?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167/66)

**Finance** (but not only)

- [Learning Finance with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8267/66)
- http://www.wolfram.com/events/chicago2011/nVidiaFinancePresentation.nb
- [High-Performance Computing in Finance](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/fin014.html)
- http://blog.wolfram.com/category/finance/
- [How can you compute Itō Integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3141/66)
  [Fast Simulations with Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14561/66)
- [Problem with Financial Data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9540/66)
- [Growth theory with Mathematica](http://www.cer.ethz.ch/resec/people/tsteger/econ_growth_mathematica_some_examples)
  [How to model Macroeconomic dynamics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13056/66)
- [Making a Stock Options Database in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28053/66)
  [How to request financial data from Yahoo's YQL and Quandl?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46760/66)
  [Graph databases / Nosql with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40731/66)
- http://www.mathestate.com/
- [How can I connect to the IB TWS platform from Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64831/66)
- [Exploring asset allocation](http://peterellisjones.com/post/39238260706/exploring-asset-allocation-with-mathematica)
- [Empirical market microstructure](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~jhasbrou/EMM%20Book/MathematicaJune2007/MathematicaContents.html)

Correlation

- [What is the best way to create a correlation matrix heatmap with values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10519/66)
- [Correcting a correlation matrix to be positive semidefinite](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10085/66)

Proba/Stats

- [DistributionFitTest[] for custom distributions in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6361647) (How to define a custom probability distribution in Mathematica 8)
- [Probability: proportion of 1000 random lists for x that contain the same nrs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11858/66)
- [Filtering beat-to-beat heart rate data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14610/66)
- [Time-series decomposition in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16723/66)
- http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/02/01/the-ultimate-univariate-probability-distribution-explorer
- [Mathematica code for hidden Markov models (HMM)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26887/66)
- [Autoregressive distributed lag model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32549/66)
- [Finding the likeliest path in a Markov process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19457/66)

**Misc**

- [Open Excel file with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/open-excel-file-with-mathematica)
  [Exporting data from Excel into Mathematica using clipboard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14658/66)
  [how to delete specific data from text file and then update it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31515/66)
- [Tricks for making graphics for the math book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748294/884752)
- [Automating SFTP upload within Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10041/66)
- [How to include Mathematica animation in a PowerPoint presentation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31511/66)
- [Calling external commands without showing command prompt on windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6876/66)
- [Web Browsing Automation with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1775/66)
- [Capturing Data from an Android Phone](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77514/66)
- [Quit the Kernel and start new session automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82803/66)
- [how to write string to file without Quotation mark](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54987/66)
- [How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/66)
  [Creating "detached" plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92470/66)
- Using parallel kernels
  [Asynchronous evaluation: Is it possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238/66)
  [Transferring a large amount of data in parallel calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2886/66)
  [Are built-in Mathematica functions already parallelized?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3674/66)
  [Does parallel programming use up large quantities of memory in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5484/66)
  [Why is this parallel evaluation with Dispatch[] so slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25263/66)
  [Computing Many Slow I/O Operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2874/66)
  [Evaluator option for Mathematica Scripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8506/66)
  [Writing data to a common file during parallel processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27189/66)
  [ParallelTable and DistributeDefinitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39178/66)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributedContexts.html
  [Suspecting bug in Parallel Framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17716/66)
  [How to share numbered variables between kernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69607/66)
  [Evaluate while external command is being run](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13520/66)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/applications/parallel/

Answer (score 16):

Not strictly a Mathematica blog but [Rip’s Applied Mathematics Blog](http://rip94550.wordpress.com/) is a very nice resource for advanced Mathematica problem solving. Rip makes regular weekly posts on whatever interests him that week and they usually include some neat implementation in Mathematica.

And another very good reference [Mathematica blog](http://mathematica-guide.blogspot.com/) by Kris Carlson with interesting methods and examples:

Comment: If bewildered one should look into examples http://rip94550.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/trusses-snow-load-on-howe-fink-and-pratt-trusses/

Comment: Thanks this blog is very interesting.

Comment: The author of this blog has passed away late last year.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure this has already been posted but I found these [tutorials](http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/13lectures.pdf) really helpful as a beginner. They are problem based (similar to the Euler Problems) and the author takes you through the solutions in a step wise fashion. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

### Blogs

- http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/
- http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/ (Blog of Yaroslav Bulatov dedicated to graph theory)
- http://12000.org (Blog of Nasser M. Abbasi)
- http://blog.matthen.com/  (Various interesting demos by Matt Henderson)
- http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.co.uk (Blog of Mike Honeychurch)
- http://textanddatamining.blogspot.com/  (Blog about data mining in texts)
- http://shuisman.com  (Blog partly about Mathematica)
- http://mathgis.blogspot.com/ (Lunchtime playground)
- http://mathematics-diary.blogspot.com (Blog of Nilo de Roock)
- http://www.walkingrandomly.com (Blog about scientific programming languages)
- http://rip94550.wordpress.com/ (Rip’s Applied Mathematics Blog, Mathematica is used to demonstrate various concepts of graduate level)
- http://mathematica-guide.blogspot.co.uk/ (Blog of Kris Carlson)
  I liked this post: [Functional-Procedural Fusion](http://mathematica-guide.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/new-mathematica-programming-style-part.html), this function is useful for this style of programming: MapEach[function_]:=(function/@#)& (for example: {1,2}//MapEach[2 #&])
- http://mathematicanews.blogspot.co.uk/

### Personal websites

- http://math.sduhsd.net/MathematiClub/ (Games, various interesting notebooks)
- http://www.theodoregray.com/BrainRot/ (Conversation with Theodore Gray one of the historical developer of Mathematica)
- http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/ (Super Widget Package, can be interesting, but using Dynamic with built-in Mathematica GUI components is now easier)
- http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/code.html  (Various interesting links to other packages)
- http://katlas.org/wiki/Main_Page  (Knot Atlas, package available)
- http://www.weber-und-partner.com/resources (Some applications to mathematical finance, package working as an interface to Quantlib)
- http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/Mathematica.html (Site of David Park, Expression manipulation and some interesting packages)
- http://www.mathestate.com (Site about finance, with some links to demonstrations)
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8073/ (A formal approach for modeling and simulation)
- http://www.bugman123.com/ (Paul Nylander)
- http://vimeo.com/groups/mathematica/videos (Some cool videos in 3D made with MM)
- http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html (Creating an Post-Processing Mathematica Graphics (on Mac OS X))
- http://www.lauschkeconsulting.net (Some interesting (non free) packages, like JavaTools which provides Mathematica links to Scala, C# and F#)
- http://www.oftenpaper.net/sierpinski.htm (Very cool pictures and math using Mathematica, code available)
- http://dev.ragfield.com/ (Useful Mathematica scripts among others. Connection with iTunes,Twitter, YouTube, Font outlines,Mapping GPS Data are some of them)
- http://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com (Blog for different methodological and algorithmic aspects of computing predictions with Mathematica.)
- http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/ (Ingolf Dahl, package implementing several interpolation methods)

**Calculus**

- http://www.wright.edu/~richard.mercer/Calculus/Lab/Download/index.html (Various notebooks about mathematics)
- https://sites.google.com/site/calcuplus/ (Introductory calculus course with CDF demos)
- http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/6111/  (Numerical analysis, code of a lot of common numerical methods)
  http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/NumericalUndergradMod.html

**Resources on other languages**

- [Having used Mathematica as a "gateway" language, where to from here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25702/66)
- Online interpreters can be found here [Online-REPs-and-REPLs](http://joel.franusic.com/w/page/26128430/Online-REPs-and-REPLs) in order to test ideas in a lot of different languages.
  https://c9.io (Cloud 9)
- This resource is very useful for common languages like Java, C++ or VBA
  http://www.java2s.com
- [C++ reference books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242)
- Tutorials on a lot of current technologies (but Mathematica is missing there ...) http://www.tutorialspoint.com
- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mathematica (Several algorithms in Mathematica together with other languages)
- http://www.cheat-sheets.org (Cheat sheets for a lot of languages)
- [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject:Computing), can be handy for a quick reference on many languages.
- [The Archive of Interesting Code](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/)
- [dGSD](http://thinkcreatesolve.biz/dGSD.html), a great tool for organizing your projects and knowledge (Based on TiddlyWiki, a wiki stored in a single HTML file).
  Or use Evernote with the [secret weapon](http://www.thesecretweapon.org/media/Manifesto/The-Secret-Weapon-Manifesto.pdf) (this thing is so good ...)
- [Alternatives to Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28162/66)
- [google-styleguide](https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/)

### Forums

**MathGroup**

- https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica
  http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forums.aspx/mathematica/201107/1
  http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/

**Stack Exchange sites**

- [Mathematica questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica)
- [Mathematica.StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) (look at "favorites" in the profiles of active users for reading past interesting answers)
- [Mathematica questions on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/filters/27192/mathematica): all questions tagged [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) on the Stack Exchange Network

### Links to some packages

- [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net/) is a comprehensive collection of links to packages
- [What third-party packages do you use?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/66)
- http://www.xact.es/index.html (Open source tensor package suite)
  also see this post [Differential geometry add-ons for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/differential-geometry-add-ons-for-mathematica) and [Tensor analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19934/66)
- [FeynRules](http://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/) by Neil D. Christensen, Claude Duhr & Benjamin Fuks (latest version: 1.6.0, package to calculate Feynman rules)
- [Automatic physical units](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/), by Jon McLoone (2010, available from the Wolfram Library Archive)
  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/
- [NCAlgebra](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) (Non Commutative Algebra Package)
- [Sym](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn) (Symmetry analysis of differential equations)
- Some packages written by Leonid Shifrin
  http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html
  https://gist.github.com/lshifr
- Various links to common websites (Google, Amazon,...), financial data, and some useful functions for manipulating time series.
  https://github.com/fmeinberg?tab=repositories
- [RUBI](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) (symbolic integration rules)
- [MTools](https://github.com/faysou/MTools) (Object oriented programming)

**Packages for preparing publication-quality scientific figures**

- [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) by Mark Caprio (latest version: 3.52, Sep 2011, for *Mathematica* 6 and higher)
- [Presentations](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/Mathematica.html) and other packages by David Park (latest version: 25 Aug 2011)
- [A WorkLife Framework](http://scientificarts.com/worklife/) by Scientific Arts LLC (extendable and customizable toolset that broadens *Mathematica*'s scope across many aspects of daily work)
- [FeynArts](http://www.feynarts.de/) by Thomas Hahn (latest version: 3.7, 27 Mar 2012, package for generation and visualization of Feynman diagrams and amplitudes)
- [Writing and Publishing a Book with *Mathematica*](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5782/) by Paul R. Wellin (2005, available from the Wolfram Library Archive)

### Useful non-free tools for development, deployment, distribution, linking, etc.

- [Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) by WRI, current version: 2 (official *Mathematica* IDE based on Eclipse, great for projects involving several packages and generating integrated documentation)
- [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) by WRI, current version: 3 ("Deploy high-powered applications as interactive websites")
- [gridMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/gridmathematica/) by WRI, current version: 8 ("Easily control CPUs and GPUs to solve large problems fast")
- [*SystemModeler*](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) by WRI, current version: 3. Integrated symbolic modelling platform.Some related links: [MathModelicaPaper](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/MathModelicaPaper.html), [ObjectMath](http://www.ida.liu.se/~pelab/omath/), [Modelica](https://www.modelica.org/), [OpenModelica](https://openmodelica.org/)
  [How to do System dynamics simulations / diagrams in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8071/66)
- [*Finance Platform*](http://www.wolfram.com/finance-platform/) by WRI, current version: 1. Includes option pricing, risk analysis, enterprise system development, and interactive reporting
- [*Mathematica* Applications and Add-Ons](http://www.wolfram.com/products/fields/) (all add-ons marketed via WRI, related to *Mathematica*)
- [Mathematica Link for Excel](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/) by Episoft, Inc., current version: 3.5 (links Microsoft Excel with *Mathematica*)

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Wolfram:
[An Elementary introduction to Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/preface.html)

Also, this does not belong 100% here but it is an overshelming list of reference to be missed.
[A Bibliography of Publications about the Mathematica Symbolic Algebra Language](ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/netlib/bibnet/journals/mathematica.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if it has already be mentioned.

[Adding Object-Oriented
Capabilities to Mathematica](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f11/presentation-materials/oomathematica_nickerson.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a beginner, and I find it interesting to explore the documentation. Some of the commands I've read about have given me interesting ideas for programs. Also, I'm not sure if this has been mentioned, but the Wolfram Demonstrations Project has a bunch of amazing programs you can play with and download the code from.

Answer (score 4):

[ApplicationMaker](https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker) shows how to create packages that look like native functionality, including integration into the Documentation Center.

Answer (score 2):

I have been adding some new content here (mostly following along with the elementary introduction book and doing explorations in machine learning):

https://www.livecoding.tv/learn/wolfram/

These 'live coding' sessions are recorded so you can watch them. They are a little bit different from pre-recorded video tutorials, because there is a chat window where 'live watchers' can ask questions (which you can not do when you watch the recording, of course).